# What does Masjävlar mean?

Tags: analysis, title, dalecarlians

I have watched the movie Masjävlar and I wonder what this title means. I have checked Google Translate but to no result. What does it and the movie refer to, and what is the essence of the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be the answer:

> DIRECTORS STATEMENT
>
> ... That they'll be a little nicer to each other, especially in
>   family settings, since there's a lot of pressure in those
>   relationships. But to begin with, I guess I wanted to tell the natives
>   of the province of Dalecarlia a thing or two as well. Half of my
>   family comes from Dalecarlia, from the region around Lake Siljan, and
>   in my opinion, they're real characters up there. It's been fun raking
>   them over the coals. At times I've been so sick of their behaviour,
>   they're so incredibly full of themselves. I mean, they'll buy a summer
>   cottage a half-hour drive from where they live just so they don't have
>   to leave the province. Dalecarlia is Sweden's heartland, and
>   everything about it is fantastic. When one of my relatives came to
>   Stockholm, we went out for pizza – the delicious gourmet stone baked
>   kind – and when we had finished our meal, this person looked at me and
>   said: "Well, our pizza place back home in Rättvik certainly knows how
>   to make a darn good pizza!" My intention was also to capture the
>   special brand of humour they have in Dalecarlia, it's simultaneously
>   warm-hearted and slightly brutal. If it isn't served up with a whole
>   lot of love, it just sounds unkind. It's like irony – when someone
>   would say "nice sweater" to you in school without really meaning it.
>   That kind of humour wears you down, it's corrosive. At the same time,
>   the film is a declaration of love to the people of Dalecarlia. You
>   know, I picked up stakes and moved from Stockholm to Dalecarlia
>   myself. These days I live in Falun and dream of being called a "kulla"
>   (the Swedish word for a female native of Dalecarlia).

Source: https://www.europeanfilmawards.eu/en_EN/film/dalecarlians.5978

Comment: How is any of that related to why the movie is titled "Masjävlar"? There's not even a single mention of the word in your answer.

Comment: @M.A.R. okay, we know that she is from Dalarna and Masjävlar is a derogatory term for people from Dalarna. In her statement, she mentions "they" are both warm hearted and brutal at the same time. And she resembles them to irony. At that point she also wants to make fun of the people in their style by using derogatory Masjävlar. It is Dalarnian since it is bitter and makes fun of them but also she shows her love to the people. We know this from her statement by: "These days I live in Falun and dream of being called 'kulla'.

These show us Blom gives the Dalarna people their own medicine.

Answer (score 3):

> The word "masjävlar" is a derogatory term for Dalecarlians, who are usually known as masar.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalecarlians_(film)

Comment: I saw that but I am not able to make connection of with the movie. It says it is derogatory but why? Is it bad to be from Dalarna? I guess there must be a reason to choose this name for the movie.

Comment: @coner I believe there is a derogatory term for everything, every race, nation, city-population, and so on. It is bad to be from China? Then why are they called Chinks? Why are Jews called Kikes? Why Yankees? etc. etc.

Comment: @TK-421 irrelevant. Some actors/actresses and director is from Dalarna. I believe Maria Blom has a reason to name the film as such.